# WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. [Ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: python, python-poetry, pyenv

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and have pyenv 2.3.11 installed and can successfully initiated a Python 3.8.13 version on it. However, whenever I try to run

```
pip install poetry
```

I get the following error

```html
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/poetry/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/poetry/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/poetry/
^CERROR: Operation cancelled by user
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I cancelled it on this last run, but that is a shortened version of the output I use. I also have the same issue with any module I try to pip install

I've tried suggestions from every other stackoverflow thread I could find with the same errors, and they include: reinstall pip, reinstall python, reinstall openssl, and I've installed a lot of other packages to try to fix this issue, but to no avail. I'd appreciate any help because I'm out of ideas and can't find any additional suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - had to correct an issue with the arrow file I was using

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue here with pyenv and pip. It occured after an upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. The solution was to simply uninstall the python version in pyenv and re-install it.